# In context of data mining, what does it mean for an association rule measure to be maximal?

Tags: terminology, data-mining

In context of data mining, what does it mean for an association rule measure to be maximal?

I cannot understand the term maximal in this context.

I know of maximal independent sets in algorithms but cannot make out this term.

Comment: can you be more precise ? where did you read this ?

Comment: but usually, a maximal subset $S$ with certain charatestics is a subset such that there is no other subset $S'$ with the same characteristics and $S \subset S$. That is, cannot extended anymore.

Comment: I read it in the following paper http://infolab.stanford.edu/~sergey/dic.html . If you search for "conviction is truly a measure of implication because it is directional, it is maximal for perfect implications". This is the statement I cannot make out

Answer (score 1):

I believe that in the context of [that paper (PS)](http://infolab.stanford.edu/~sergey/dic.ps), you can read "maximal" as "maximized". That is to say, the conviction function $P(A)P(\neg B)/P(A, \neg B)$ attains its greatest value when $A \implies B$.